# Spring XD 1.1.0 - JDBC Source connection issues

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, spring-xd

I have installed SPRING-XD version 1.1.0 on a Centos machine. Using `xd-singlenode` I want to connect it to a SQL Server database via jdbc source and put the data into file.

I created some streams as follows:

```
1)xd:>stream create connectiontest --definition "jdbc  --url=jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserverhost:1433/SampleDatabase --username=sample --password=*****   --query= 'SELECT * FROM schema.tablename' |file" --deploy

2)xd:>stream create connectiontest --definition "jdbc  --connectionProperties=jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserverhost:1433/SampleDatabase --username=sample --password=*****   --initSQL= 'SELECT * FROM schema.tablename' |file" --deploy
```

Everytime I deploy the stream it gives the following error:

> Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Multiple top level module resources found :file [/opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/jms-hornetq.properties],file [/opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/hadoop.properties],file [/opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/xd-admin-logger.properties],file [/opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/xd-singlenode-logger.properties],file [/opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/xd-container-logger.properties],file [/opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/jms-activemq.properties],file [/opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/httpSSL.properties]

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I set springxd_home pointing to my springxd directory. After removing the path it is working fine now.

Thanks for the support.